# How to disable deployment of smart contracts on besu private network?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, gas, hyperledger, besu

Is there any way to disable creation of smart contracts on Hyperledger Besu Private Network for addresses except those that I specify? I want to create private network with zero gas fee, but no one can deploy smart contracts except me.

Or is there a way for besu to specify what opcodes costs gas, so i could set all opcodes to be zero gas, but CREATE opcode to cost gas?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `create-contract-permission` branch in [permissioning-smart-contracts](https://github.com/ConsenSys/permissioning-smart-contracts) repo. Seems like alpha stage, but probably with some additional work, you can use [Besu's permissioning](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Concepts/Permissioning/Permissioning-Overview/) with updated contracts to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11091/is-there-any-way-to-disable-contract-creation-on-a-private-network), and the answers are:

- Filter contract creation transactions on validator/mining nodes
- Make `CREATE` opcode unreachably costly.